# Is it possible to display individually the image that is inserted using shopify themes?

Tags: html, css, shopify

I kind of want to display the image individually without using for loop so that I can edit them.

```html
<div class="col">
  {% for block in section.blocks %}
    <img src="{{ block.settings.image | image_url: width: 250}}">
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I tried different method but none of it work. I expect to individually put the image into their container.

Comment: Try like this `section.blocks[0].settings.image`

Comment: yes, you can remove the loop and start from 0 to your number of blocks to access a particular image.

Comment: Hi, may ask if you know how to make the "type": "image_picker"  in the schema into a background? What syntax do I need?

Comment: you need to use the inline style on HTML element or inline CSS into same section to render the image from image picker to use it as background.